# Set of all hidden assumptions in a statement

Tags: logic, epistemology, argumentation

Imagine a person "**A**" who says to a person "**B**" the following statement: *"It is true that the house in front of me has three windows"*. If you think about it, this statement is true for a person "**B**" only if "**B**" interprets the words in this statement the same way as the person "**A**" does. Let's say for example, that by the word "true" used in the statement a person "**A**" meant to convey the meaning "corresponing to an *objective reality*". However if this was the meaning of the word "true" the person "**A**" had on his mind, then it is obvious that the person "**A**" implicitly assumes the existence of an objective reality. So for a given statement to be at least a bit more convincing, a person "**A**" should explicitly add his implicit assumptions like "I assume you interpret the words used in my argument the same way as I do. I also assume objective reality, etc.." Sure, we could find much more hidden assumtions in the statement - note that the statement is only a poor example.

I wonder how philosophers call this set of all assumtions which one has to assume in a statement? The thing I often find confusing is that someone says something as a fact without giving me all his implicit assumtions (sometimes they even don't realize those assumtions). This is often the case in some mathematical or scientific paper in which they suppose some level of expertise in the subject and so they don't explicitly say the things they assume. Imagine a mathematical paper about e.g. linear algebra in which they use a theorem in some calculation without stating explicitly that this is a theorem and that the theorem was proved based on some particular axioms and reasoning.

I would be also glad if you could give some your thoughts on this topic or to recommend some further reading and key words. Thank you.

(note: My expertise is not in philosophy, so easy on me please)

Comment: " proposition P s true for some person B" ... can be argued to mean nothing more that " person B believes that P is true" ... in that case the question is not on truth conditions but on belief conditions

Comment: Background assumptions and background knowledge.

Comment: But something in your post alludes to a potential "skeptical" issue: how can be certain that we correctly understand each other ? No way to be certain... But this is not a "logical" issue; maybe useful [Private Language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/private-language/).